# set color for Modern UI application

Tags: windows-8, themes, winrt-xaml, modern-ui

I want to set custom color for my Modern UI application. This color will be used for selection borders in GridView\ListView and other places.

P.S. I know, that I can change style for GridViewItem, but I want to see this color in all places, where it can be seen for application.

Answer (score 1):

The long winded way is to override the application theme resources one by one to get the colours you want. I've talked about this solution before at [Overriding Metro app resources](http://www.markermetro.com/2012/07/technical/windows-8-overriding-metro-app-resources/).

It's pretty time consuming and there's a lot of variations to deal with. The best way to do it is with an open source tool called [Hammer.Pants](https://github.com/Code52/HAMMER) which is a little command line exe that given a colour will generate the full gamut of application resources for you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to restyle all controls where the selection color is used.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to override list of brushes. May be this code will help somebody:

```
private List<string> ResourcesColors = new List<string>
        {
            "PageAccentBrush",
            "ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ListBoxItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ProgressBarForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush",
            "SliderTrackDecreaseBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SliderTrackDecreasePointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SliderTrackDecreasePressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchCurtainBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchCurtainPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchCurtainPressedBackgroundThemeBrush"
        };

    private void ApplyColorsToResources()
    {
        if (this.Resources.ContainsKey("PageAccentBrush"))
        {
            SolidColorBrush pageAccentBrush = this.Resources["PageAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;

            if (pageAccentBrush != null)
            {
                SolidColorBrush scb = null;
                foreach (var item in this.ResourcesColors)
                {
                    scb = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources[item];
                    scb.Color = pageAccentBrush.Color;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```